# reseed sql server identity columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I reseed identity columns like this:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable "DBCC CHECKIDENT ( '?', RESEED, 0)"
```

Query throws me an error if there's no identity in the table. But I still need to reseed identity for all tables in the database that have an identity. (And do not throw an error if there's no identity)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are all the tables really empty?

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'DBCC CHECKIDENT(''' 
    + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]))
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME([object_id])) 
    + ''', RESEED, 0);' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE is_identity = 1;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: This code throws the error "DELETE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'" whenever they are used on a table that has computed columns. Any idea how to change the above script to make it work with computed columns (also apparently happens with indexed views, filtered indexes, query notifications, spatial index operations and XML data type methods)?

Comment: @Marchy well, did you have `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` when you created any of these tables? Did you try adding `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;` to the beginning of the script (before the `DECLARE` should be fine)?

Comment: Aaron thanks for the super-quick reply. I tried setting `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;' at beginning of script but the same error happens. I've never set the option explicitly to OFF during any table creation (and it seems SQLServer default is ON). The tables were all created by Entity Framework migrations, I looked into the generated creation script and the option isn't set there either. Is it possible to rewrite the above query to not rely on quoted identifiers to be turned to ON?

Comment: @Marchy sorry, without knowing exactly which part of your schema is causing the problem, I can't tell you what to fix. There is no option to DBCC CHECKIDENT that says "ignore any SET option setting conflicts" and I also didn't have any problem issuing DBCC CHECKIDENT against tables (including those with computed columns) even when QUOTED_IDENTIFIER was off. Can you set up a full reproduction of the error on [sqlfiddle.com](sqlfiddle.com)? Otherwise I can't really help without pulling teeth all night long, and hockey's on.

Comment: Got it! Upon further investigation the error was thrown on a `EXEC sp_msforeachtable "DELETE FROM ?"` line just before the code above (line 149 in the [AppHarbor bulk update library](http://bit.ly/17VIZLc). Apparently sp_msforeachtable has `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` set in its body. Solution was to prepend "SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;" to the command executed by `sp_msforeachtable` (as mentioned [here](http://bit.ly/12GPdwf)). Big thanks for the help!

Comment: @Marchy you really should think twice about using `sp_msforeachdb` (for this and other reasons): https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/12/29/a-more-reliable-and-more-flexible-sp-msforeachdb.aspx

Answer (score 2):

To reseed all tables to 0 that have an identity column in one line:

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'dbcc checkident(''?'', reseed, 0)', @whereand='and exists(select 1 from sys.columns c where c.object_id = o.id and is_identity = 1)'
```

> Checking identity information: current identity value '33798', current column value '0'.
>   DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
>   Checking identity information: current identity value '3359', current column value '0'.
>   DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

Answer (score 0):

For any table:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RESEED](@Tabla nvarchar(100))

as


/* 
create function  dbo.FN_EsIdentidad(@Tabla nvarchar(100), @Campo nvarchar(100))
    returns int
    as
    begin
        return columnproperty ( object_id ( @Tabla  ), @Campo , 'IsIdentity')
    end 
GO

*/


declare @CampoIdentidad nvarchar(100)

    SELECT @CampoIdentidad  = Column_Name
        --,dbo.FN_EsIdentidad(Table_Name, Column_name) as EsIdentidad,
        --table_name, column_name 
        FROM information_schema.columns
        where dbo.FN_EsIdentidad(Table_Name, Column_name) = 1 
        and Table_Name=@Tabla


declare @Sql nvarchar(max)
declare @OutPutNum int
set @Sql = 'Select MAX(' + @CampoIdentidad + ') From ' + @Tabla
--select @CampoIdentidad


set @sql = 'Select @ValorOut=COALESCE(max(' + @CampoIdentidad + '),0) From ' + @Tabla 
declare @ParamDefinition nvarchar(max)
SET @ParamDefinition = '@ValorOut int OUTPUT'

EXECUTE sp_executesql  
    @SQL 
    ,@ParamDefinition  
    ,@ValorOut = @OutPutNum OUTPUT;  

--select @SQL


DBCC CHECKIDENT (@Tabla, RESEED, @OutputNum)

> Blockquote
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just truncate the table if there are no Record in the table.
This will reset the primary key.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE '?'
```

Comment: the problem is `I still need to reseed identity for all tables in the database that have an identity. ` OP says ALL TABLES that have an identity.

Comment: Please add more details to your answers. `truncate table '?'` on its own would not work. complete solution please.